# get checkbox value in to a variable

Tags: php, checkbox

This is my checkbox

```
<input name="interests2" type="checkbox" value="double-deep-racks" />
```

This is how I am trying to get that value in to a variable

```
$int = $_POST['interests2'];
```

Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong. I cant get the values I just get blank.

Comment: `$_POST` items will have the same key as the input `name` attribute. In your case, it is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$int = $_POST['interests2'];
```

If you are trying to set multiple checkboxes you can do something like,

```
// Your html
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="This is i">
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Another i value">

// php
$email = "Further Information In: \n";
foreach($_POST['interests'] as $i)
         $email .= $i . "\n";
```

Comment: sorry. My bad. it should be interest2. the issue Is i have few checkboxes but I Dont want to put them in to a array.

Comment: if I set a loop. how can I add them to a email   $email_message .= "Further Information In: ".clean_string($int)."\n";

Answer (score 2):

The name of your checkbox is `interests2`. You must get the value by that name like this:

`$int = $_POST['interests2'];`

Comment: sorry it was right name. i mistakenly added a wrong one here. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` element must match what you are looking for.  In your input field the name is `interests2` but you are looking for `interests` (missing "2").

Also, you may possibly need to look in `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`, depending on the form or the AJAX method you are using (you didn't post that portion of your code).

Comment: @PradeepWickramanayake Well did you find it in `$_POST` ? From comments on other answers, it sounded like you did, and it was the "2" typo. If you have still not found it, add `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to your script. This should show all data sent in the request, and you will see where it is. If nothing is output, then there is something wrong with the code that's sending the request